# Определение входящего номера в состоянии OFFHOOK при 2ух одновременных звонках

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

Здравствуйте. Может кто сталкивался с решением данной проблемы: Я отслеживаю ин-фу о входящем звонке, поднятой трубке и окончании вызова и отправляю её на сервер. При обработке одинарного звонка проблем никаких нет. Но при звонке по второй линии появляется проблема:

Схематично это можно представить так

```
Действие            Состояние телефона
-------------------------------------
Звонит <номер1>  |  RINGING (EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER == <номер1>)
Подняли <номер1> |  OFFHOOK (EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER == null)
Звонит <номер2>  |  RINGING (EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER == <номер2>)
Подняли <номерX> |  OFFHOOK (EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER == null) <--- Час Ч
Положили трубку  |  IDLE (EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER == null)
```

Как узнать что произошло в "Час Ч":

1. Сбросили номер1 и перешли к номер2
2. Сбросили номер2 и вернулись к номер1
3. Отложили номер1, перешли к номер2, вернулись к номер1 и ещё сколько угодно манипуляций

Что бы не происходило *EXTRA_STATE* всегда равен **OFFHOOK**, *EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER* всегда **null**, да и вообще **BroadcastReceiver**, натравленный на *android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE*, перестаёт срабатывать.
**PhoneStateListener** мне не подходит, т.к. при звонках на вторую симку его **state** всегда равен 0, да и по-моему он не даёт решения.

Если нужен код, скажите выложу.

Как быть? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Пока что не удалось решить проблему целиком, но требуемый результат частично получен.

Задача у меня стоит своевременно отправлять информацию о входящих звонках на сервер. Изначально, при появлении второй линии, проблема была в том, что по окончании звонка на сервер приходила ин-фа лишь о последнем вызове, а первый повисал активным. Это проблема решилась сохранением номеров в локальную базу и просмотр этой базы по состоянию IDLE. Проблема с повисанием активных вызовов решилась, но появилась другая - вне зависимости от действий, произошедших в "Час Ч", оба звонка по IDLE получали одну дату окончания и ни один из них не мог быть пропущенным. Несколько часовое ковыряние гугла навело на класс CallLogs.Call и теперь, когда телефон переходит в режим IDLE номера достаются из локальной базы (ActiveCallsDB в коде) и из CallLogs.Call достаётся продолжительность последнего разговора с данным номером. Моя конкретная проблема решена, хоть и нифига не изящно, буду рад, если кому-то пригодится. Но вопрос остаётся открытым.

```
if (state.equals("RINGING")) {
        ringing = true;
        number = incomingNumber;
        intentForService.putExtra("number", number);
        cont.startService(intentForService);

        SQLiteDatabase db = (new ActiveCallsDB(cont)).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("phone", number);
        cv.put("status", "0");
        db.insert(ActiveCallsDB.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();

    } else if (ringing && state.equals("OFFHOOK")) {
        intentForService.putExtra("number", number);
        intentForService.putExtra("state", 2);
        cont.startService(intentForService);

        SQLiteDatabase db = (new ActiveCallsDB(cont)).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("phone", number);
        cv.put("status", "2");
        db.update(ActiveCallsDB.TABLE_NAME, cv, "phone = ?", new String[] { number });
        db.close();
    } else if (ringing && state.equals("IDLE")) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                // Ждём, пока ин-фа о звонках запишется в базу Android-а
                this.wait(1000);
            }
            SQLiteDatabase db = (new ActiveCallsDB(cont)).getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ActiveCallsDB.TABLE_NAME, null);
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String phoneNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("phone"));

                    String[] projection = new String[] { Calls.NUMBER, Calls.DURATION };
                    Cursor curForCall = cont.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, "number = ?", new String[] { phoneNumber },
                            Calls.DATE + " desc");
                    curForCall.moveToFirst();
                    String duration = curForCall.getString(1);
                    curForCall.close();

                    intentForService.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
                    intentForService.putExtra("state", 1);
                    intentForService.putExtra("duration", duration);
                    cont.startService(intentForService);

                    db.delete(ActiveCallsDB.TABLE_NAME, "id = " + cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("id")), null);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
            ringing = false;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму зачем вы пытаетесь ловить номера в онлайне. Если Вам необходимо просто определять входящие звонки и отсылать их на сервер, то проще повесить обозреватель и читать изменения списка вызовов по факту их окончания.

> ContentObserver mContentObserver = new CallLogContentObserver(new
>   Handler(), context, "");
>               context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
>                       android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
>                       true,
>                       mContentObserver);